# Как заставить один поток работать на все ядра?

Tags: c#

У меня есть программа для вычислений, есть 1 проблема - она работает на одном ядре и заполняет его на 100%, не трогая остальные ядра, сама программа может работать только в 1 потоке (Вычисления нельзя делать асинхронно).
Я же хочу что бы она работала на всех ядрах (Можно и без полной работы, хотя бы 200% на всех ядрах), искал в инете инфу - везде разная, но ни один метод не сработал.
Может у кого такая проблема была? Можете помочь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А нет никакого метода, так что я сомневаюсь, что у Вас какие то методы не сработали. Поток работает на одном ядре. Хотите загрузить больше ядер - запустите больше потоков. А распараллеливанием вычислений человечество занимается давно, и, возможно, Ваша задача тоже поддаётся распараллеливанию. и еще - а у Вас программа не на питоне?

Comment: Тогда как возможно запустить ровно 4 потока, по одному потоку на каждое ядро?

Comment: Можно. посмотрел на метку - Вам достаточно просто заустить 4 параллельных задачи, дальше планировщик сам разберётся. А если у Вас 4 ядра с гипертредингом, так что можно даже 8 задач запустить.

Comment: @S.H. сбиваете человека с толку, оперируя магическими числами. Хотя-бы формулу подсказали `Enviroment.ProcessorCount * 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я в коде использовал SetThreadInfinityMask, из-за чего у меня поток работал только на первое ядро, по стандарту и поток делится (Переходит) на различные ядра https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NZRb.png
Вероятнее всего @S.H был прав, нужно запустить 4 потока и на каждый поток с помощью SetThreadInfinityMask наложить своё ядро.

Заметил кстати что с SetThreadInfinityMask получается менее потребляющий поток, ибо ему не нужно постоянно переходить на другие ядра ради балансировки.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132481/discussion-on-answer-by-yotic--------).